# GoogleMaps API on React duplicating maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a React App (based on create-react-app) in which I type a city in an input, and the app makes an API call to a weather service and saves the result in an array of "cities". Then I map that array and display the data of all cities I have on my array. Every time I type a new city, a new item is added to my page (with the weather information of that place).
For the maps, altough, I'm having a problem. Even though I'm passing the right props (lat and lon), all the items show the same map (the map of the first city to be searched). I tried using also those NPM packages (google-map-react, google-maps-react), and I have exactly the same problems.
That's my code:

```
const google = window.google;
const mapStyle = {
    width: 200,
    height: 225
  };

class GoogleMap extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {
        lat: this.props.lat,
        lng: this.props.lon
      }
    });
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref="map" style={mapStyle}/>
  }
}

export default GoogleMap;
```

Then how I use in in my component:

```
class WeatherList extends  Component {

  render() {
    if(this.props.weather.length === 0) {
      return <div></div>;
    }
    const cities = this.props.weather.map((city, index) => {
      const list = city.list;
      const temp = list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);
      const pressure = list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
      const humidity = list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
      const {lon, lat} = city.city.coord;

      return <Table.Row key={index}>
        <Table.Cell verticalAlign='top' style={{'width':'250px', 'height':'250px'}}>
          <GoogleMap
            lat={lat}
            lon={lon}
          />
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell verticalAlign='bottom'>
          <Sparkline data={temp} color="blue" unit="&#8451;"/>
          <div>{city.city.name}</div>
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell verticalAlign='bottom'>
          <Sparkline data={pressure} color="red" unit="hPa"/>
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell verticalAlign='bottom'>
          <Sparkline data={humidity} color="green" unit="%"/>
        </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    });
    return (
      <Table basic='very'>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell width="3">City</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Temperature</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Pressure</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Humidity</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.Body>
          {cities}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

It's not a problem of Key or not calling the API, because it's calling. I can see the maps. The problem is it reapeat the same map (although all the other data: name, temperature, pressure, is different).